# Checkbox Grid into Single List Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I'm new to using checkboxes to manipulate my excel files. I've got a grid of 51 check boxes, over 6 columns (as shown in the image linked below) is it possible to index the grid and give me a single list array showing which checkbox is showing as True ?

[image: Example Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines, assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then this should work :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, TOCOL(B2:G18),
     b, WRAPROWS(a,2),
     TOCOL(IFS(TAKE(b,,1),DROP(b,,1)),3))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:G18),2),
     TOCOL(IFS(TAKE(α,,1),DROP(α,,1)),3))
```

---

If you need a sorted array then use the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:G18),2),
     σ,TOCOL(IFS(TAKE(α,,1),DROP(α,,1)),3),
     SORTBY(σ,TEXTAFTER(σ,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)))/1))
```

---

Comment: =LET(S,TOCOL(REPT(C2:G18,B2:F18),3),FILTER(S,S>""))